# With sendmailR, how can I specify a recipient/sender name along with the address?

Tags: email, r, smtp, sendmail, postfix-mta

I am using [sendmailR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/index.html) to send emails but I cannot get it to work with a name associated with the email addresses, like `"Sender name" <sender@domain.com>`

With Postfix as the SMTP server, it throws `SMTP Error: 5.5.4 Unsupported option: <sender@domain.com>`.

Which syntax or parameter should be used? Your advice is welcome!

Following the example:

```
from <- "\"Sender name\" <sender@domain.com>"
to <- "<olafm@datensplitter.net>"
subject <- "Hello from R"
body <- list("It works!", mime_part(iris))
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))
```

Comment: I updated the question to include sample code.

Comment: Have you tried `from <- "Sender name<sender@domain.com>"`?

Comment: Are you really using `ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM`, or is that a placeholder instead of your real SMTP server?

Comment: This is a placeholder, the actual SMTP server is a local postfix.

Answer (score 2):

From one side, one e-mail address can't contain any whitespace non-quoted, it should have a form `"\"Sender name Or Any name with any whitespace you want\"<sender@domain.com>"`.

And from the other side, e-mail addresses used in *to* and *from* fields format depends on the server.

For example, when using Google's **ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM** SMTP I was only able to write the addresses in the following form:

`from <- "<sender@domain.com>"`

Options like

- `"\"Sender name\"<sender@domain.com>"`;
- `"\"Sender name\" <sender@domain.com>"`;
- `"Sender name<sender@domain.com>"`;
- or `"Sender name <sender@domain.com>"`

were not accepted and generated either

> SMTP Error: 5.5.2 Syntax error.

(for the 1st option) or

> SMTP Error: 5.5.4 Unsupported option

(for options 2-4, I suppose, because of whitespace).

But when I tried custom SMTP server, I was able to use both `from <- "<sender@domain.com>"` and `"\"Sender name\"<sender@domain.com>"` - the second one gave exactly what I expected to get.

Answer (score 1):

You must not include any space between the quoted name and the email address enclosed in <>. Here is the correct code:

```
from <- "\"Sender name\"<sender@domain.com>"
to <- "\"Recipient name\"<olafm@datensplitter.net>"
subject <- "Hello from R"
body <- list("It works!", mime_part(iris))
sendmail(from, to, subject, body,
control=list(smtpServer="ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"))
```