# sendmailR specify sender name

Tags: r, sendmailr

I am trying to specify a sender name while using sendmailR to send emails. I refer to this post([With sendmailR, how can I specify a recipient/sender name along with the address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558344/with-sendmailr-how-can-i-specify-a-recipient-sender-name-along-with-the-address?rq=1)), but it seems to me that the solution does not work properly, I got this error message:

> Error in wait_for(code) : 
>     SMTP Error: Syntax error, parameters in command "MAIL FROM:  "Sender name"< sender@domain.com>" unrecognized or missing

Anyone can help?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [mail](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mail/index.html) package which offers an alternative way to sent mail via an external mail server and address

Example:

```
require(mail)
sendmail("xyz@abc.com", "Mail", "TEST") // sendmail(to,subject,body)
```